# Autocomplete textbox are not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

controller:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->model('select');
        }
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('index'); 
            if(isset($_GET['term'])){
            $location = strtolower($_GET['term']);      
            echo $this->select->autoload($college_name);          
            }  
        }
    }
```

view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#colleges" ).autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/collegescan_ci/index.php/test/search",
                        data: { term: $("#colleges").val()},
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                                return obj.college_name;
                           }); 
                           response(resp);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
<input type="text" name="colleges" id="colleges"/>
```

model:

```
<?php
  class Select extends CI_Model{
    public function autoload($term)
      {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT college_name FROM all_colleges where college_name like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$term."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END");
        echo json_encode($query->result_array());
      }
  }
```

I am new in codeigniter and I want to create an autocomplete textbox. In this code I am created an autocomplete textbox which is not working. I don't know why ? can anybody help me please.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the codeigntor manual.As per codeigntor manual the model name should be like this 'Yourmodelname_model' also not sure you can give model name as 'Select',

```
class Select_model extends CI_Model{
    function autoload() {
        $row_set = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like('college_name', $college_name);
        $query = $this->db->get('venue_details');

        if (count($query->result_array()) > 0) {
          foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
              $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['college_name']));
          }

        }
        return json_encode($row_set);
     }
  }
```

Please refer codeigntor giude,

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Comment: change your model declaration part like following ,

class Select_model extends CI_Model{